# How to make in R matrix of intersections and unions over categories?

Tags: r

Let's have this data

```
> allt <- data.frame(day = rep(c("mon", "tue", "wed"), each =3), id = c(1:3,2:4,3:5))
> allt
  day id
1 mon  1
2 mon  2
3 mon  3
4 tue  2
5 tue  3
6 tue  4
7 wed  3
8 wed  4
9 wed  5
```

In the final data frame we can see that for day "mon" we have ids [1,2,3] and for "tue" we have [2,3,4]. So if we make  intersection of these vectors we get [2,3] and if we make union we get [1,2,3,4] . The lengths of these vectors are 2 respectively 4 and the ratio is 0.5. That is the number I want to get.

So I am looking for a generalized way how to get this ratio over more categories for all possible combinations.

The result could be in a format something like a correlation matrix. Just to be clear I am interested in intersections and union of 2 categories so e.g I don't need a 4-way intersection (Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu) - just each 2 day intersection.

Comment: What would your expected output like for the given example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
days <- levels(allt$day)

f <- function(x, y) {
  xids <- allt$id[allt$day == x]
  yids <- allt$id[allt$day == y]
  length(intersect(xids, yids)) / length(union(xids, yids))
}
f <- Vectorize(f)

outer(days, days, f)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  1.0  0.5  0.2
# [2,]  0.5  1.0  0.5
# [3,]  0.2  0.5  1.0
```

optionally pipe that into `set_colnames(days)` and `set_rownames(days)`

Comment: What does the "Vectorize" do?

Comment: The unvectorized `f` does not operate properly on vectors supplied to it (the functions within can also take vectors, `f` just passes the vector through). `Vectorize` basically wraps the function into `sapply` for each element of x and y applying recycling rules and such so that each invocation is called with scalar arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This here should do the trick, and you can also make more combinations but changing the value in the combn-function.

```
# Creating your dataset
monday<-data.frame(day=rep("mon",3),id=c(1:3))
tuesday<-data.frame(day=rep("tue",3),id=c(2:4))
saturday<-data.frame(day=rep("sat",3),id=c(3:5))
allt<-rbind(monday,tuesday,saturday)

# Creating a list of values pr day    
library(dplyr)
aggregated_form <- allt %>%
  group_by(day) %>%
  summarise(ids = list(id))

# Function takes a list with two vectors and make intersect/join    
intersecter <- function(list_of_lists) {
  vec1 <- unlist(list_of_lists[1])
  vec2 <- unlist(list_of_lists[2])
  my_intersect <- intersect(vec1, vec2)
  my_union <- union(vec1, vec2)
  ratio <- length(my_intersect)/length(my_union)
  return(ratio)
}

# Creates strings with all combinations
combination <- sapply(combn(aggregated_form$day,2, simplify = FALSE), paste, collapse = "-")

# Calculates you value for all combinations
values <- combn(aggregated_form$ids, 2, FUN = intersecter)

# Generates a dataframe with results
results <- data.frame(comb = combination,
                      value = values)
results
     comb value
1 mon-tue   0.5
2 mon-sat   0.2
3 tue-sat   0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
combn(unique(allt$day), 2, function(x) 
{length(intersect(allt[allt$day == x[1],]$id, allt[allt$day == x[2],]$id)) / length(unique(allt[allt$day == x[1] | allt$day == x[2],]$id))
}, F
)

[[1]]
[1] 0.5

[[2]]
[1] 0.2

[[3]]
[1] 0.5
```

Edit: to create the "day-combinations-names", something like this can be done to obtain those in the corresponding order as for the ratios:

```
lapply(combn(unique(allt$day), 2, ,F), paste, collapse = "-")

[[1]]
[1] "mon-tue"

[[2]]
[1] "mon-sat"

[[3]]
[1] "tue-sat"
```

Comment: I am not, no need to be rude.. You could argue we took a comparable approach (even though that could be argued as well), but I did not even not even see your post before I posted mine.

Comment: Or is it just about creating the "day-combination-names"? Yes I see now that single line is almost the same, but no worries I copy-pasted your answer. Sometimes great minds think alike ;)

Comment: You cannot spell great without 8 :-|

Answer (score 1):

first create a matrix for results for intersections:

```
int<-mat.or.vec(nr=length(unique(allt$day)),nc=length(unique(allt$day)))
colnames(int)<-unique(allt$day)
rownames(int)<-unique(allt$day)
```

replicate matrix for unions:

```
un<-int
```

calculate intersections and unions:

```
for(col in colnames(int)){
  for(row in colnames(int)){
    int[row,col]<-length(intersect(allt[allt$day==col,"id"],allt[allt$day==row,"id"]))
    un[row,col]<-length(union(allt[allt$day==col,"id"],allt[allt$day==row,"id"]))
  }
}
```

Then you just have to divide both matrices:

```
int/un

     mon tue sat
 mon 1.0 0.5 0.2
 tue 0.5 1.0 0.5
 sat 0.2 0.5 1.0
```